# Moving a range with mouse w/o being perturbed by script induced movements

Tags: javascript, html, range

I have a range input in a HTML page, which actually stands for a music timeline. I got a script that moves the handle along the slider as the music progresses.
Now, I want to be able to move the handle so the music will play where I set the handle with the mouse.
The problem is that when I begin dragging the handle along the slider, as soon as its position is updated by the script, it is set to its actual position and I lose control over it.
How can I fix that so I can move my handle freely ?
To play the music I am using a plugin, soundmanager2, and I am using the provided `whileplaying` callback function to set the position of the slider as the music progresses.

Here is the HTML bit :

```html
<div id="timeCtl">
    <span id="timeRange">
        <input id="time" type="range" value="0" min="0" max="1000"/>
    </span>
    <p id="timeCpt">00:00 / 00:00</p>
</div>
```

And the JS that goes with it :

```js
//This is the callback function contained within an object being created
whileplaying : function() {

    //This whole block processes the "position / duration" display
        var dur = parseInt(this.duration/1000, 10);
        var durMin = parseInt(dur/60, 10);
        var durSec = dur%60;

        var pos = parseInt(this.position/1000, 10);
        var posMin = parseInt(pos/60, 10);
        var posSec = pos%60;

        if (posMin < 10)
        {
            posMin = "" + "0" + posMin.toString();
        }
        if (posSec < 10)
        {
            posSec = "" + "0" + posSec.toString();
        }
        if (durMin < 10)
        {
            durMin = "" + "0" + durMin.toString();
        }
        if (durSec < 10)
        {
            durSec = "" + "0" + durSec.toString();
        }

        var displayDur = durMin.toString() + ":" + durSec.toString();
        var displayPos = posMin.toString() + ":" + posSec.toString();

        g("timeCpt").innerHTML = displayPos + " / " + displayDur;

    //And here is the part that take care of moving the handle
        var curPos = parseInt(pos / dur * 1000, 10);
        g("timeRange").innerHTML = "<input id=\"time\" type=\"range\" value=\"" + curPos.toString() + "\" min=\"0\" max=\"1000\">";
        //The problem is that it moves the handle while I'm dragging it and then I lose control and have to grab it again
        //How to avoid that ?
}
```

Thank you for your time reading this, and thank you in advance for your answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I may have found a way to solve the problem.
I could make things so that when the onclick event is fired, the script moving the range is disabled, until the onrelease event is fired (totally not sure about the events names but I guess find out what they really are).
I'm gonna try this out and keep the thread up to date.

**EDIT:** This works.

- Create a boolean variable.
- Surround the *updating* part of your script with a condition controlled by the boolean variable.
- Set the boolean variable to false when the slider's *onmousedown* event is fired, and it will prevent the script from updating it.
- Set it back to true when *onmouseup* is fired, with some additionnal processing if needed.